# git allow one directory while exclude rest folder in .gitignore fle

Tags: wordpress, git, gitignore

I have a Wordpress website in which I have code as shown below:

wp-content/uploads/

which exclude uploads wp-content/uploads/ from git commit. But now I reached to the case where I have to include a subfolder **wp-content/uploads/MY_CUSTOM_PDF**

How should I only allow **MY_CUSTOM_PDF** to be included in git commit while ignore the rest as it was earlier.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.gitignore exclude folder but include specific subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533050/gitignore-exclude-folder-but-include-specific-subfolder)

Answer (score 0):

**Solution** already exist.!!

> [.gitignore exclude folder but include specific subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533050/gitignore-exclude-folder-but-include-specific-subfolder)

if sometimes git command-line ignore not work due to already uploaded folder so use `smartgit`  ignore unwanted error